# how to modify some of the contents of the file and save in the same file using java

Tags: java

I have a text file of words and their frequency count. When I give any word, which matches with a word in text file, then I need to increment its frequency count. How to change the values in the text file? How to do this process in Java. Please suggest any ideas. Thanks in advance.

```
myfile.txt

word    4
self    5
defence 3
argue   7
```

When I give the word "self", then in the same text file of "myfile.txt", it need to overwrite as

```
word    4
self    6
defence 3
argue   7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not directly answering you question, consider using `java.lang.Properties` to manage the file:

- each *word* is a unique value and can be used a property name (key)
- the frequency count is the value to be associated with each *word*
- `Properties` has `load()` and `store()` methods for reading from and writing to files

Answer (score 2):

You can't insert characters in a text file, you can only *replace* or *append* data.

In other words, if you go from `9` to `10`, you'll have to shift all characters following the `9` one step to the right, to make room for `10`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way, IMHO, is to use a thrid party API that takes care of all the reading and writing. My favourite for this is http://commons.apache.org/io/
Check out the class FileUtils. I think it contains all the methods you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could read/write to the file, if you would use enough room for writing increasing values, by filling in some blanks, for example:

```
word    4___
self    11__
defence 3___
argue   7___
```

But you would need an upper limit to know in advance.

You could use a binary representation and store 32-bit ints in 4 bytes, but then you would lose human readability of the file.

The typical solution for your problem is a database, which were made for such jobs - it might look oversized, but today, there are many small in-memory databases available. The last time I used one it was hsqldb some years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Use a

```
Map<String,Integer> words = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

to store all the words count.
Then you can easily save all the keys to a file in the format you prefer